# Is it possible to treat indices of an Array like Members of a Struct?

Tags: objective-c, c, struct, unions

So I have this struct composed of three NSPoint structures.

```
typedef struct AOTriangle_ {
    NSPoint a;
    NSPoint b;
    NSPoint c;
} AOTriangle;
```

I would like in some cases to reference the points as a,b,c and other cases as indices into an array.

Like so,

```
AOTriangle t;
t.a = NSMakePoint(0,0);
t.b = NSMakePoint(3,0);
t.c = NSMakePoint(0,4);

for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    t[i].x += 5.0;
    t[i].y += 5.0;
}
```

This is the closest I've gotten, but you can see it isn't exactly what I wanted.
Is there a way of doing this in Objective-C? Is the a better way than what I do below of accomplishing something similar - maybe with a union?

```
typedef struct AOTriangle_ {
    NSPoint a;
    NSPoint b;
    NSPoint c;
} AOTriangle;


AOTriangle t;
t.a = NSMakePoint(0,0);
t.b = NSMakePoint(3,0);
t.c = NSMakePoint(0,4);
NSPoint* t = (NSPoint*)&triangle;
for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    t[i].x += 5.0;
    t[i].y += 5.0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use a "[union](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_%28computer_science%29)".  I believe the declaration would go something like this:

```
typedef struct AOTriangle_ {
    union {
        struct {
            NSPoint a;
            NSPoint b;
            NSPoint c;
        };
        NSPoint points[3];
    };
} AOTriangle;
```

A `union` is basically a way of saying "I can refer to the members of this struct as either `a`, `b`, or `c`, or as `points[0]`, `points[1]`, or `points[2]`."

And you would use it like this:

```
AOTriangle t;
t.a = NSMakePoint(0,0);
t.b = NSMakePoint(3,0);
t.c = NSMakePoint(0,4);
for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    t.points[i].x += 5.0;
    t.points[i].y += 5.0;
}
```

Comment: Are unions rarely used? I've never even heard of them before and I'm pretty confident I've never seen one.

Comment: They are not at all uncommon in C. Especially low level programming.

Comment: @kubi That can only be a consequence of having done very little C programming.

Comment: That is awesome. Looks so simple now. I didn't think about putting the union inside the struct. Thanks so much!